# Firebase Ui Demo authentication error

Tags: android, firebase

[the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfq38.png)So I dowloaded the firebase ui demo from git hub and its seemed to run fine except when I go to register as a new user with gmail or email sign up I get an error that says, "email registration unsuccessful". I found in code were its throwing the error in a function called registerUser(). Its in a file called RegisterEmailFragment.java (https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/ui/email/RegisterEmailFragment.java), on line 313. Any ideas? Keep in mind I do have gmail and email/pass enabled on the firebase console.

Comment: share your app log.

Comment: added the log to question